# Twilio SMS call through java enterprise proxy failing with the below error

Tags: java, twilio, httpclient

Followed the steps in Twilio website:

reference link: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java/custom-http-clients-java

Getting error:
Exception in thread "main" com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.twilio.exception.RestException.fromJson(RestException.java:53)
    at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create(MessageCreator.java:508)
    at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create(MessageCreator.java:25)
    at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:45)
    at com.publix.forgotpassword.Services.SendSMSService.SendSMSService(SendSMSService.java:36)
    at com.publix.testClasses.SMSTestingClass.main(SMSTestingClass.java:11)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:693)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:591)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2630)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:832)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:729)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3070)
    at com.twilio.exception.RestException.fromJson(RestException.java:51)
    ... 5 more

Anyone can help me on this please?

Comment: I think you are using C# code with a Java compiler.

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java/custom-http-clients-java

Comment: Above are the exact url. i will edit the post now.

Comment: Looks to be complaining about the format of your message

Comment: Thanks All, I have figured it out. Sample code in Twilio site dont work if your enterprise proxy looks for credentials. Need to add few other lines of coding to pass credential to pass proxy authentication. i have added credential as part of HTTP client and then it started to work. Thanks everyone for your help! This issue is resolved now.