# Twilio Whatsapp call through java enterprise proxy failing with Unexpected character code 60

Tags: java, http, twilio, twilio-api

I've followed these steps exactly- https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java/custom-http-clients-java
for creating custom TwilioRestClient. I'm even passing my enterprise proxy host and proxy port as suggested and twilio credentials in ProxiedTwilioClientCreator. The code is exactly same as given in the Twilio Website. Only difference is that I'm trying to send Whatsapp message so the phone numbers have "whatsapp" appended at the beginning. It is working perfectly in my home desktop. But I'm facing the following error in my work system. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Getting error: Exception in thread "main" com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 2] at com.twilio.exception.RestException.fromJson(RestException.java:53) at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create(MessageCreator.java:508) at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create(MessageCreator.java:25) at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:45) at ...

Comment: Take a look at what the response is. It looks like there is xml arriving at a place where json is expected.

Comment: No, that's not the case. It has something to do with my enterprise proxy...the message call is not getting through.

Comment: i disagree. Where is that `<` char coming from then?

Comment: You can see the details here also, but the question is unanswered... 
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753775/twilio-sms-call-through-java-enterprise-proxy-failing-with-the-below-error